# Sphinx: how to include docstrings/comments located well within a module, but outside of class and methods

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a comment in my python module that documents several classes that follow, e.g.

```
###

# Classes for agents: patients and clinicians

###

class EngagementLadder(transitions.Machine):
    """The state machine for agent states.
```

In fact there are several such multi-class comments. Each serves to break up the file, together organizing it into related sections.

I would like to see those comments in the generated documentation, perhaps as headers. How to do that?

Note that my question is similar to [In Sphinx, how to include docstrings/comments located in a module, but outside of class and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071959/in-sphinx-how-to-include-docstrings-comments-located-in-a-module-but-outside-o), but the answer that worked for him---putting it in the module docstring---will not work for me as I want these comments further down the file.

Comment: Would modifying the .rst file be an adequate workaround? It would mean copying the comment and making it compliant with reST syntax, but it might give you the placement and formatting you desire.

Comment: There is no obvious way to do what you want. Sphinx processes docstrings, not comments. Also note that there can be only one toplevel docstring per module.

Comment: You know, this inability to process non-docstring comments is really a shame.  I've managed to set up sphinx to do a lot with my project... and since I use ``autodoc_member_order = 'bysource'`` I generally get my documentation in the order of my source code.  I have places where I group methods by an abstract concept, like ``state transition event handler``.  Wouldn't it be great to add section header comments??

Answer (score 0):

One method of achieving this is to use dummy variables

I.e. The below will add a section heading

```py
SECTION_A = "SECTION A"
"""Section A contains some useful stuff about my project...

It can span multiple lines...

"""

def foo():
    """Description of foo"""
    pass

#: Section B contains some useful stuff about my project...
#: It can span multiple lines
SECTION_B = "SECTION B"

def bar():
    """Description of foo"""
    pass
```

Documentation here: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute

Answer (score 0):

For a module level comment, you can add to the [docstring](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-docstring) for the module. This will appear at the head of the generated documentation for the module

```
__doc__ = """This will appear as doc level comments in the sphinx output.

Continuation here...
"""

def example_fun(some_input: int, text_input: str = "") -> str:
    ...

__doc__ += "\n Can continue here, but it will also show up at doc level"
```

In sphinx you get something like this:

```html
<section id="module-sphinx_example">
<span id="sphinx-example-package"></span><h1>sphinx_example package<a class="headerlink" href="#module-sphinx_example" title="Link to this heading">¶</a></h1>
<p>This will appear as doc level comments in the sphinx output.</p>
<blockquote>
<div><p>Continuation here…</p>
</div></blockquote>
<p>Can continue here, but it will also show up at doc level</p>
<dl class="py class">
<dt class="sig sig-object py" id="sphinx_example.BaseClassEx">
<em class="property"><span class="pre">class</span><span class="w"> </span></em><span class="sig-prename descclassname"><span class="pre">sphinx_example.</span></span><span class="sig-name descname"><span class="pre">BaseClassEx</span></span><span class="sig-paren">(</span><em class="sig-param"><span class="n"><span class="pre">a_string</span></span></em>, <em class="sig-param"><span class="n"><span class="pre">int_with_def</span></span><span class="o"><span class="pre">=</span></span><span class="default_value"><span class="pre">2</span></span></em><span class="sig-paren">)</span><a class="reference internal" href="_modules/sphinx_example.html#BaseClassEx"><span class="viewcode-link"><span class="pre">[source]</span></span></a><a class="headerlink" href="#sphinx_example.BaseClassEx" title="Link to this definition">¶</a></dt>
<dd><p>Bases: <code class="xref py py-class docutils literal notranslate"><span class="pre">object</span></code></p>
<p>Just a base class, not much to see here.</p>
<p>Note: the args for the constructor are listed as part of the class documentation and not the __init__. In fact,
unless you tell doc/src/conf.py to include the __init__ it will ignore them (and all the other dunter methods)</p>
<dl class="field-list simple">
<dt class="field-odd">Parameters<span class="colon">:</span></dt>
<dd class="field-odd"><ul class="simple">
<li><p><strong>a_string</strong> (<em>str</em>) – Any old string will do</p></li>
<li><p><strong>int_with_def</strong> (<em>int</em><em>, </em><em>optional</em>) – Give me an int, or don’t that’s fine too. Defaults to 2.</p></li>
</ul>
</dd>
</dl>
</dd></dl>
```